# How to search and combine elements inside NSDictionaries as arrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

As a concrete example, suppose I have the following array of dictionaries, which share the same keys and value types:

```
[ {car: "Ferrari", make: "Italian", color: "red"},
  {car: "Ferrari", make: "Italian", color: "yellow"},
  {car: "Porsche", make: "German", color: "green"},
  {car: "Porsche", make: "German", color: "silver"}
]
```

How would I be able to search only by a key (for example, by "car") through the dictionaries, and then combine the values that are different (in this case, the "color") as arrays, so that my resultant array is:

```
[ {car: "Ferrari", make: "Italian", color: ["red", "yellow"]},
  {car: "Porsche", make: "German", color: ["green", "silver"]},
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far to convert the data from the 1st format into the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method will solve your problem:

```
- (NSArray*) combineValuesFromArray:(NSArray*) array byKey: (NSString*) key
{
    NSMutableSet *differentValues = [NSMutableSet set];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array)
    {
        [differentValues addObject:dict[key]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSString *value in differentValues)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSMutableDictionary *sets = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for(NSDictionary *dict in filteredArray)
        {
            for(NSString *dictKey in dict)
            {
                NSMutableSet *set = [sets[dictKey] mutableCopy];
                if(set == nil) set = [NSMutableSet new];
                [set addObject:dict[dictKey]];
                sets[dictKey] = set;
            }
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for(NSString *dictKey in sets)
        {
            newDict[dictKey] = ([sets[dictKey] count] == 1) ? [sets[dictKey] anyObject] : [sets[dictKey] copy];
        }
        [result addObject:[newDict copy]];
    }
    return [result copy];
}
```

I've used following code for testing:

```
NSString *car = @"car";
NSString *make = @"make";
NSString *color = @"color";
NSArray *array = @[ @{car: @"Ferrari", make: @"Italian", color: @"red"},
                  @{car: @"Ferrari", make: @"Italian", color: @"yellow"},
                  @{car: @"Porsche", make: @"German", color: @"green"},
                  @{car: @"Porsche", make: @"German", color: @"silver"}
                    ];
NSLog(@"%@", [self combineValuesFromArray:array byKey:car]);
```

Comment: This code assumes that `car` is the unique key (which is true with the tiny bit of sample data). The OP will need to make adjustments if it turns out that the combination of `car` and `make` are the unique key.

Comment: Could you please provide and example that will not work? The OP did not say anything about keys combinations.

Comment: Imagine a case where two rows have the same `car` value but different `make` values. This may never be the case but if it can happen, your solution will give incorrect results. I only point this out to the OP just in case it is a real issue of the real data.

Comment: I've changed make for one of Ferraries to German. Here is the result:  (
        {
        car = Ferrari;
        color = "{(\n    red,\n    yellow\n)}";
        make = "{(\n    Italian,\n    German\n)}";
    },
        {
        car = Porsche;
        color = "{(\n    silver,\n    green\n)}";
        make = German;
    }
)
I think it's ok.

Comment: That result is not correct at all. The results should be an array of colors for each unique pair of car/make. In your results, which is red? The Italian or German Ferrari?

Comment: The OP wrote: "and then combine the values that are different (in this case, the "color") as arrays" so I guess he understand that not only one but few values may be different.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. After rereading the question I see how both interpretations could be right.

Comment: Thank you both - I tried the result that @Sviatoslav wrote and it has worked.  Sorry I did not get around to posting my original attempt earlier.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv Thank you for the answer.  My only issue is that now the outputs have a lot of \n attached to it, such that when I use the test array I get the following for "color": `color = "{(\n    red,\n    yellow\n)}";`.  How would I be able to remove the line breaks?  Thanks!

Comment: Use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert array to string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with a little better time complexity. The first function `convertDataBasedOnKey` will receive the value from which you may want to compare, as you said on the question you wanted to be *searchable by a key*. The second function `getSharedDictionaryOfElements` is just for creating the final dictionary with the values merged.

```
- (void)convertDataBasedOnKey:(NSString *)baseKey {

    desiredFormatData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableString *filterString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ ==",baseKey];
    [filterString appendString:@" %@)"];

    while (currentFormatData.count != 0) {

        NSDictionary *aDictionary = [currentFormatData firstObject];
        NSString *firstValue = [aDictionary objectForKey:baseKey];
        NSArray *filtered = [currentFormatData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                             [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filterString, firstValue]];
        NSDictionary *mergedDictionary = [self getSharedDictionaryOfElements:filtered sharingValueForKey:baseKey];
        [desiredFormatData addObject:mergedDictionary];

        [currentFormatData removeObjectsInArray:filtered];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",desiredFormatData.description);
}

- (NSDictionary *)getSharedDictionaryOfElements:(NSArray *)anArray sharingValueForKey:(NSString *)aKey {

    if (!anArray || anArray.count == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    // As all the elements in anArray share the same keys
    NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *modelDictionary = [anArray firstObject];

    for (NSString *aKey in modelDictionary.allKeys) {
        NSPredicate *filterByKey = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
        NSArray *resultArray = [[anArray valueForKey:aKey] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterByKey];
        NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:resultArray] allObjects]];
        [resultDictionary setObject:uniqueArray forKey:aKey];
    }
    return resultDictionary;
}
```

**Example**

Using this two functions to obtain what you asked will be something like this:

Having declared this two variables:

```
NSMutableArray *currentFormatData;
NSMutableArray *desiredFormatData;
```

Then filling the first one with the example data and making the operation based on a key "**car**":

```
currentFormatData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@{@"car":@"Ferrari", @"make":@"Italian", @"color":@"red"},
                                                     @{@"car":@"Ferrari", @"make":@"Italian", @"color":@"yellow"},
                                                     @{@"car":@"Porsche", @"make":@"German", @"color":@"green"},
                                                     @{@"car":@"Porsche", @"make":@"German", @"color":@"silver"}]];

[self convertDataBasedOnKey:@"car"];
```